# Call a method using switch case from another C file?

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to call methods "choice_1" & "choice_2" from the Choice.c file, using switch case statements I wanted to call the options after an input was taken in the Menu.c file and return the results, the menu is in a loop and works, I know this because I moved the methods from the Choice.c file into the Menu.c file, a few adjustments and everything works, but not when they are in separate files...

I have "#includes Menu.h" in the header of both files.

I also have 2 functions in the header file:

```
void choice_1(int * count, char * text);
void choice_2(int * count, char * string);
```

When I try to compile Menu.c I get

> [Linker error] undefined reference to 'choice_1'
>
> [Linker error] undefined reference to 'choice_2'

Menu.c

```
int main(void){
int count[2];
...
while(TRUE) {
      printf("%s\n", "Menu:");
      printf("%s\n", "1) Option 1");
      printf("%s\n", "2) Option 2");
      ...
      printf("%s\n", "5) Exit");         
      fgets (userinput)...
...
      switch(userinput){
          case 1:
              choice_1(count);
              break;
          case 2:
              choice_2(count);
              break;
          ...
          case 5:
              return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
              break;
...
```

Choice.c

```
....
void choice_1(int * count, char * text){
....
}
void choice_2(int * count, char * string){
....
}
```

It just doesn't call the 2 methods, What am i doing wrong ? :S

Comment: What are you typing at the command line to do your compilation?

Comment: `return` isn't a function. Use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.

Comment: @mbratch you were right my command line compilation lacked some detail. :)

Comment: Could you show some actual code?  `fgets` takes three arguments, not one, for example, and what is the type of `userinput`?  (And I don't see where you convert the input from characters into some type of integer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try to compile Menu.c I get

```
    [Linker error] undefined reference to 'choice_1'

    [Linker error] undefined reference to 'choice_2'
```

This is because your function definitions  are in another file. you need to compile both at a time.so that you can get rid of linker error

if you compile like this you can get rid of this linker error

```
gcc menu.c choice.c -o out
./out
```

Comment: **Trust the error messages**. When they say `linker error`, then you know it's a problem with your object code linking.

Comment: @DavidRTribble Yes You absolutely correct.Looking at errors will solve max issues.

Answer (score 3):

Your functions `choice_1` and `choice_2` is expecting two arguments while you are passing only one argument to `choice_1` and `choice_2`.

```
switch(userinput){
      case 1:
          choice_1(count);  
          break;  //   ^ only one argument
      case 2:
          choice_2(count);
          break;  //   ^ only one argument
```

Also change

```
return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

to

```
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Yes but when i pass 2 arguments i get "too many arguments to function"

Comment: Show you functions please.

Comment: I want to see your function definition.

Comment: sry abt the confusion, Thanks for your help tho haccks ! :)

Comment: Changing `return(EXIT_SUCCESS);` to `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` isn't totally necessary. Although I also much prefer the latter, I've seen style patterns that use the parentheses.

Comment: @mbratch; True. But one should avoid this because `return` is statement and not function.

Answer (score 3):

Once you get the signatures for your functions matching in all the files, you need to 'link' choice.c file too to menu.c as it contains the definition for `choice_1` and `choice_2` . Otherwise, the compiler doesn't find the definition of those two functions and hence throws the error - `[Linker error] undefined reference to 'your_function_name'`

Comment: how do i link the two please ? and I assume by signature you mean the code should be matching across all files ?